# Diagnose website slow startup AJAX ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, ajax, performance

I've a Ajax .net website which follows this structure :

- Control (ascx) : TopMenu, LeftPanel, RightPanel, Footer, all are very simple controls and don't require any connection to database or server side code !
- One div body (ajax)

Everytime the website starts, the 4 controls load first, then comes the Ajax body. The performance is pretty good in development environment.

But when i uploaded the precompiled site to the host, it always take quiet long for starting up, after the first load, the performance is good

What i can't understand is : as far as i know, the four ascx control will be rendered first, that means the page will be loaded to the client, after that is the ajax content. So what's causing the performance on start up ?

P/s :

- i did set the key compilation=false in web.config
- i compiled the site using Publish tool in VS 2010 (Release mode and not allow updatatable ... )
- i have no images on the site, it's a very simple site
- i've checked similar topics, and event posted a question not so long ago about
  this, but still without success
- my site: http://iketqua.net

Comment: They can be hundred of reasons, actually without the real site personally I can not say anything.

Comment: My site : http://iketqua.net

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your site and running the Network Analysis on google chrome what is blocking the render of your site is a huge delay for make a lot of calculations on page load, there is a lot of time that takes to start get data.

Also the google analytic script, must be placed on bottom of your page, together with other external scripts for google plus, facebook like etc.

Also there are 2 fonts on this css, that can not be load, and this takes almost 3 seconds delay.

`http://iketqua.net/Styles/Fonts/MyriadPro/font.css`

[image]
<sub>(source: [planethost.gr](http://planethost.gr/so/ExSiteTest101.jpg))</sub>

Comment: Thanks i will try to fix all things you mentioned

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to the very first request after deployment to production. I don't think there's anything you can do about it. ASP.NET first request will always be slow, even if it is a pre-compiled site because the server still needs to load resources on the server-side.

But, if you are talking about first load from the client-side perspective, by just running Chrome Developer Tools I can see that your site's home page is quite heavy (44 requests, ~4 seconds to load) which explains why the first load takes some time and sub-sequent requests are quicker...mainly, because most of those 44 requests get cached by the browser. Now, in your dev environment it happens quickly because there is no significant network latency or connection hops, once you move to production the network lantency and connection hops plays a big role in performance...that's why many sites use CDNs.

#### Suggestions

Make your site lighter. There's many things you can avoid. For example:

1. This background image (http://iketqua.net/img/header_bg.png) is useless because it is a plain color which you can easily achieve that using css. That'll translate to one request less
2. Bundling and minification tools to minify and merge style sheets and js files
3. Optimize your css. Take the time to review your css and clean it. I can't believe that such a simple page can be requesting 9 css files...probably most of them are coming from open source frameworks (jQuery UI, DatePick, etc)

Comment: Thanks i will try to fix all things you mentioned

Comment: Cool, glad to help but don't take my word for it without scrutiny. Make your own research and keep an eye for things you can improve...at the end of the only you have access to your project

Answer (score 0):

I lack permissions to post this as a comment, but if it's fine in the development environment, it may be something as simple as ability of the host or the connection to the host.

> After the first load, the performance is good

I'd be inclined to think this is due to the site being cached.